# TypeError: 'int' object is not callable in (multiplication table)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I will use a nested loop to create a multiplication table range, to print table, but showing error.

#### Code:

```
tables = int(input("Enter table"))


for table in range(2,tables+1):
    for num in range(1,11):
        print(f"{table} * {num} = {table*num}")
```

#### Error:

> ````
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-23-b1cb99dac75d> in <module>
>       2 tables = int(tables)
>       3 
> ----> 4 for table in range(2,tables+1):
>       5     for num in range(1,11):
>       6         print(f"{table} * {num} = {table*num}")
> TypeError: 'int' object is not callable```
> ````

Comment: Did you accidentally name a variable `range`?

Comment: no range is function

Comment: Yes, range is normally a function. However, running your code as it sits doesn't produce this error. The only way I can get that error is by running something like `range = 10; for i in range(20): print(i)`. In that snippet, `range` is aliased and is now an `int` instead of the builtin function and is not callable

Comment: i will try to run this code on online compiler its running but running on jupyter notebook showing error 'int' obj is not callable

Comment: I'd check through the rest of the cells of your jupyter notebook. Make sure you are not defining `range = <some_int>` anywhere

Comment: @MuhammadArsalan Before the loop, just insert `print(range, type(range))` and check the result; likely it will be type `int`. You can also check `import builtins; print(range is builtins.range)`; likely this will print `False`.